# Polyfit with negative exponent

Tags: matlab, octave, curve-fitting

I want to fit a curve to my data points (x;y) that will have a formula as such:

```
1/y = (x^-1)*a + b
```

At first I wanna do this using Octave but later I have to code this into microcontroller using c.

A quick search on google and matlab documentation don't give an anwesr I can't find a function that do polyfit with elements with negative order.

Is there a special set of function for such operation or do I have to somehow transfer my formula to fit into standard math problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your unknowns are `a`and `b` which are both linear in your problem. So you can use the 1st order polynomial fitting. It is already in the form of a standard math problem. To see just rename

```
Y = a*X + b
```

with the known data vectors (or points)

```
Y = 1/y
X = 1/x
```

Thats all.